# Couldn't import and download Data.List.Ordered in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I'm too beginner in Haskell and I wrote a simple program that imports Data.List.Ordered, when I run the program this error appears:

```
test.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module `Data.List.Ordered'
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Data.List.Ordered ( isSorted, nub )
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then I tired to download the package  using the following command:

```
cabal install --lib --package-env . ordered
```

but It didn't work as well

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cabal install --lib --package-env . ordered
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.7 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - ordered-0.1 (lib:ordered) (requires build)
Starting     ordered-0.1 (all, legacy fallback)
Building     ordered-0.1 (all, legacy fallback)

Failed to build ordered-0.1.
Build log (
C:\Users\reema\Desktop\Haskell\cabal\logs\ghc-8.10.7\ordered-0.1-e612131c8de88f5b62dca269575aa8273bdac512.log
):
Preprocessing library for ordered-0.1..
Building library for ordered-0.1..
[1 of 3] Compiling Data.Poset.Internal ( Data\Poset\Internal.hs, dist\build\Data\Poset\Internal.o )

Data\Poset\Internal.hs:32:10: error:
    * No instance for (Semigroup PosetOrd)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid PosetOrd'
   |
32 | instance Monoid PosetOrd where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal-3.6.2.0.exe: Failed to build ordered-0.1. See the build log above for details.
```

These versions I'm using:

```
GHCi,  version 8.10.7
Cabal, version3.6.2.0
```

Comment: The [`ordered` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ordered-0.1/docs/Data-Poset.html) is very old, hasn't been maintained to keep up with newer GHC versions, and anyway doesn't contain a module `Data.List.Ordered`. You may be looking for [`data-ordlist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0) instead (which is also pretty ancient, though). What put you on towards those ordered lists anyway? [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Map.html) seems a better choice for most purposes.

Comment: Besides: it is preferrable to _never install any packages_ manually. Instead, you should put them as _dependencies_ in your `.cabal` file.

Comment: I have reported the build failure with `ordered` in https://github.com/miguelpagano/ordered/issues/1, and created a revision.